# Regular expression not allowing a and c to be next to each other

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression which doesn't allow 'a' and 'c' to be next to each other in any combination of "abc" , the combinations might be "a" , "b" , "c" , "acb" , "abac" , here "abac" must be ignored because it contains "a" and "c" next to each other , I've written a regular expression which is doing half the job correct and the other half incorrect , it's basically ignoring a , bcb , bcc and others which are not supposed to be ignored.

Here's the regular expression :

```
^(a?b)*c?$
```

Here's the output I'm getting :

```
[a, b, c, ba, ca, ab, cb, ac, bc, baa, caa, aba, cba, aca, bca, 
bab, cab, abb, cbb, acb, bcb, bac, cac, abc, cbc, acc, bcc]
b 
c 
ab 
bc 
bab 
abb 
abc
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Is `abaaac` really supposed to be allowed?

Comment: @Darkman I've edited the question and added my output

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry I meant abac , I've edited the question

Comment: `abc` does not contain `a` next to `c`. You must be thinking of `\b(?:(?!(?:a\w*c|c\w*a))\w)+\b` which allows separation and reversals where `a` and `c` not allowed together in a word.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Your question indicated that the  strings could be more than just 3 characters.  e.g.  "abac".

Comment: Not really a job for a regular expression. Just scan for `"ac"` and `"ca"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler straightforward regex. Rather than thinking to exclude the pattern, you can also match the pattern and ignore them like following example:

```java
String[] str = {
    "a", "b", "c", "ba", "ca", "ab", "cb", "ac", "bc", "baa",
    "caa", "aba", "cba", "aca", "bca", "bab", "cab", "abb",
    "cbb", "acb", "bcb", "bac", "cac", "abc", "cbc", "acc", "bcc"
};
        
for(int i=0; i<str.length; ++i) {
    if(str[i].matches("ac.?|.?ac|ca.?|.?ca")) {
        System.out.println("MATCH: " + str[i]);
    } else {
        System.out.println(str[i]);
    }
}
```

This makes the following output:

```
a
b
c
ba
MATCH: ca
ab
cb
MATCH: ac
bc
baa
MATCH: caa
aba
cba
MATCH: aca
MATCH: bca
bab
MATCH: cab
abb
cbb
MATCH: acb
bcb
MATCH: bac
MATCH: cac
abc
cbc
MATCH: acc
bcc
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression ignores several cases:

- anything with more than one `c` is ignored
- anything with `a` or `b` coming after `c` is ignored (that means if there is a `c` that has to be the last character)
- anything containing an `a` is ignored if it doesn't contain also a `b` after that `a`
- each `a` must be followed by a `b`
- also your grouping is probably not really the form you need. You should use `(?:X)` for a non capturing group.

I would suggest a regex like

```
^(?:(?:a(?!c))?b?c?)+$
```

This matches all `a`s not followed by a `c` and also all `b`s and `c`s - and needs at least one occurence so that empty strings are not matched.

You can play with it and get detailed explanations at https://regex101.com/r/DoyUPG/1

Answer (score 1):

In spite of your provided data, you said `"the combinations might be "a" , "b" , "c" , "acb" , "abac" , here "abac"` which indicates they could be more than just three letters.  Rather than use a `regex` I recommend `String.contains`.

```
String[] str = { "a", "b", "c", "babbacb", "ca", "ab", "cb",
        "aeseac", "bc", "baa", "caa", "aba", "cba", "aca",
        "bca", "bab", "cab", "abb", "cbbabcda", "acb",
        "bcbacbae", "bacadbac", "adecdcac", "abc", "cbc",
        "acc", "adbbcc", "abac" };
        
for (String s : str) {
    if (!(s.contains("ac") | s.contains("ca"))) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

prints

```
a
b
c
ab
cb
bc
baa
aba
cba
bab
abb
cbbabcda
abc
cbc
adbbcc
```

But if you want to use a `regex` then simply check for those strings that
matches string that is composed of at least one `ac` or `ca`.

```
String regex = ".*((ac)|(ca)).*";
for (String s : str) {
    if (!s.matches(regex)) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

prints the same as above.